# How can i show this inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $n>1$ and $a_1,...,a_n \in \mathbb{R}^+$ be such that $\sum a_i=1$. For evey $i$, define $b_i=\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}a_j$. Show that

$\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{a_k}{1+b_k}\ge \dfrac{n}{2n-1}$

Thanks a lot for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $b_i=1-a_i$. Thus using AM-HM inequality gives

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{a_k}{1+b_k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{a_k}{2-a_k}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{(\frac{2}{2-a_k}-1)}& =2\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{2-a_k}}\right)-n \\
& \geq \frac{2n^2}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{(2-a_k)}}-n \\
&=\frac{2n^2}{2n-1}-n \\
& =\frac{n}{2n-1}
\end{align}

Comment: It's awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy-Schwarz:

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\dfrac{a_k}{1+b_k}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}((1+b_k)a_k)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\dfrac{a_k}{1+b_k}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}((2-a_k)a_k)\geq (\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_i)^2=1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$

By Cauchy-Schwarz:

$\sum (a_i)^2\sum 1\geq \sum (a_i)=1 \Rightarrow -\sum (a_i)^2\leq -\dfrac{1}{n} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$

Dividing both sides in the last inequality of $(1)$ by $\sum_{k=1}^{n}((2-a_k)a_k)$ and applying $(2)$ we are done.